# control char is not working through website

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am validating the control character in a given string.
This is an input string from the front end(react).

below are the peace of code.

```
string strValue = "contol\nchar";
    for (int ctr = 0; ctr < strValue.Length; ctr++) {
        if (Char.IsControl(strValue, ctr)) {
            Console.WriteLine(false);
        }
    }
```

It is working fine when I am debugging in my local system and postman,
but not working when I deployed the code.

[image]

kindly help me.
Thanks

Comment: Please define exactly what you mean by ‘not working’ and where and how the code is deployed.

Comment: Log the actual input reaching the failing code and compare if there is a difference to your  postman setup.

Comment: @stuartd I M expecting to validate the input string from web page, code is deployed to server(linux).

Ralf - added a log message, no difference in my postman setup working fine for other APIs

Comment: I bet your control character was replaced with a space on the frontend.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov looks no, i hv attached log file screen shot.